# Taking two streams and combining them in OCaml

Tags: stream, ocaml, record

I want to take two streams of integers in increasing order and combine them into one stream that contains no duplicates and should be in increasing order. I have defined the functionality for streams in the following manner:

```
type 'a susp = Susp of (unit -> 'a)
let force (Susp f) = f()

type 'a str =  {hd : 'a ; tl : ('a str) susp }

let merge s1 s2 = (* must implement *)
```

The first function suspends computation by wrapping a computation within a function, and the second function evaluates the function and provides me with the result of the computation.

I want to emulate the logic of how you go about combining lists, i.e. match on both lists and check which elements are greater, lesser, or equal and then append (cons) the integers such that the resulting list is sorted.

However, I know I cannot just do this with streams of course as I cannot traverse it like a list, so I think I would need to go integer by integer, compare, and then suspend the computation and keep doing this to build the resulting stream.

I am at a bit of a loss how to implement such logic however, assuming it is how I should be going about this, so if somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Your type is equivalent to non-empty sequences from the standard library https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.11/libref/Seq.html (except for empty sequence). Also, are your input sequences sorted themselves?

Comment: Yes, the input sequence is sorted as well, forgot to specify that. And thanks for the link!

Comment: You can also look at Jane Street's [Sequence](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/base/Base/Sequence/index.html) module, which is Seq on steroids and has a `merge` function.

Comment: If you still want to implement it yourself for learning purposes, I took a stab at it that I could share. Holding off for the moment on the chance that this is homework (plus, while it looks reasonably correct, I didn't test it yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the the input sequences are sorted, there is not much difference between merging lists and sequences. Consider the following merge function on lists:

```
let rec merge s t =
  match s, t with
  | x :: s , [] | [], x :: s -> x :: s
  | [], [] -> s
  | x :: s', y :: t' ->
    if x < y then
      x :: (merge s' t)
    else if x = y then
      x :: (merge s' t')
    else
       y :: (merge s t')
```

This function is only using two properties of lists:

- the ability to split the potential first element from the rest of the list
- the ability to add an element to the front of the list

This suggests that we could rewrite this function as a functor over the signature

```
module type seq = sig
  type 'a t
 
  (* if the seq is non-empty we split the seq into head and tail *)
  val next: 'a t -> ('a * 'a t) option

  (* add back to the front *)
  val cons: 'a -> 'a t -> 'a t
end
```

Then if we replace the pattern matching on the list with a call to `next`, and the cons operation with a call to `cons`, the previous function is transformed into:

```
module Merge(Any_seq: seq ) = struct

  open Any_seq

  let rec merge s t =
    match next s, next t with
    | Some(x,s), None | None, Some (x,s) ->
      cons x s
    | None, None -> s
    | Some (x,s'), Some (y,t') ->
      if x < y then
        cons x (merge s' t)
      else if x = y then
        cons x (merge s' t')
      else
        cons y (merge s t')

end
```

Then, with list, our implementation was:

```
module List_core = struct
  type 'a t = 'a list
  let cons = List.cons
  let next = function
  | [] -> None
  | a :: q -> Some(a,q)
end
module List_implem = Merge(List_core)
```

which can be tested with

```
let test = List_implem.merge [1;5;6] [2;4;9]
```

Implementing the same function for your stream type is then just a matter of writing a similar `Stream_core` module for stream.